# How find this ODE $(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y=-2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

> Find the ODE
>   $$(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y=-2$$

I think we can find 
$$(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y=0$$
I have find a solution $y=x$,But I can't find all solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting $y=1+f(x)$, we have that $f$ satisfies:
$$(1-x^2) f'' + 2x f' - 2f = 0, $$
that can be solved using Frobenius' method. By setting:
$$ f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} a_j z^j $$
we have:
$$ z\,f'(z) = \sum_{j=1}^{+\infty} j a_j\, z^j,\qquad f''(z)=\sum_{j=2}^{+\infty}j(j-1)a_j z^{j-2} $$
$$(1-z^2)f''(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\left((j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}-j(j-1)a_j\right)z^j$$
so:
$$(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2}-j(j-1)a_j+2ja_j-2a_j = 0 $$
or:
$$(j+2)(j+1)a_{j+2} = (j-1)(j-2) a_{j}\tag{1} $$
so the relation $a_{j+2}=\frac{j-1}{j+1}\cdot\frac{j-2}{j+2}a_j$ gives that the solution associated with the initial conditions $a_0=0,a_1=1$ is given by $f(x)=x$ while the solution associated with the initial conditions $a_0=1,a_1=0$ is $f(x)=x^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to $(1-x^{2}) w'' + 2x w' - 2w = 0$ is given by $w(x) = A (x-1)^{2} + B x$. The solution to $(1-x^{2})y'' + 2x y' - 2y = a$ is given by $y(x) = A(x-1)^{2} + B x - \frac{a}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *finding an ODE* means *solving an ODE*, if you have shown that $y_1(x) = x$ is a solution of $L(y) = 0$, then seek solutions of the form $y(x) = A(x) y_1(x)$, which leads you to:

$$(1-x^2) (A'' y_1 + 2 A'y_1' + A y_1'') + 2 x (A'y_1 + A y_1') - 2 A y_1 = -2,$$

or, equivalently:

$$ A''  + A' \, (2y_1'/y_1 + 2x/(1-x^2)) = -2/(y_1(1-x^2)). $$

Can you solve for $A(x)$?

Cheers!

Comment: Equivalently? How can you guarantee that any solution of the first equation is also a solution of the second equation? Putting in a different manner, why is it that finding all the solutions of the bottom equation gives all solutions for the given equation?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the original 2nd order ODE, $L(y) = p(x)$, is linear and hence its solution is of the form $y(x) = Ay_1(x) + B y_2(x) + y_p(x)$. The OP has shown that $y_1(x) = x$ is a solution of $L(y) = 0$. Then, the method of variation of parameters ensures the finding of the complete solution, doesn't it?

Comment: My issue is with the division by zero. For instance note that the function which is constantly $1$ (defined on the whole real line) is a solution to the given differential equation, but not to the last one in your answer.

Comment: My example above is correct, but unnecessary, the issue here is the domain of the solutions. The bottom one doesn't yield solutions defined at $1$ or $-1$, so solutions are lost.

Comment: I see, that woul be because $x=\pm 1$ are singular regular points of the equation. You can expand about these points by using Fröbenius method but I still don't see your point.

Comment: My point is the following. Let $g\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto 1$. The function $g$ is a solution to the given differential equation, but not the one after the division, so clearly solving the one you propose, does not solve the given differential equation.

Answer (score -1):

That is a Legendre equation. Deriving a solution on your own will be very difficult. Here is some information about it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials